# Counting length of array containing comma separated strings

Tags: javascript

Below is my array:

```
var array = ["abc.mp3,Lmn.mp3","pqr.mp3","ppp.mp3,ggg.mp3"];
```

Now I want to count length of this record but I would like to treat comma separated records as not a single record

**For eg: abc.mp3, Lmn.mp3 want to to treat as 2 separated records by splitting with comma.**

**Expected length of array should be: 5**

Is there any method which will simplify the process of counting this length instead of doing loop and then splitting each record by comma and then counting length one by one?

Comment: what code have you written to solve this?

Comment: nothing built in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

join array as string and then split string to array,then you can calculate the array `length`.

```js
var array = ["abc.mp3,Lmn.mp3","pqr.mp3","ppp.mp3,ggg.mp3"].join(',').split(',');
console.log(array);
console.log(array.length);
```

Comment: Just a pointer, comma is the default join value. You can ignore `','` in join

Comment: @Rajesh if to ignore `,`  in join,how to split it into array?

Comment: Join joins elements using comma itself as default.

Comment: yes,I know it,but join the array with `,` explicit may be let someone known clearly.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind effort efforts towards helping me.Thanks you so much and please keep helping like this :)

Comment: It's my pleasure.Not at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over array and create a new array that will have split values. Now you just have to do `newArray.length`

```js
var array = ["abc.mp3,Lmn.mp3","pqr.mp3","ppp.mp3,ggg.mp3"];

var ret = array.reduce(function(p,c){
  return p.concat(c.split(','));
}, [])

console.log(ret.length)
```

Or, you can create a string and count number of commas and just add 1 to it

```js
var array = ["abc.mp3,Lmn.mp3","pqr.mp3","ppp.mp3,ggg.mp3"];

console.log(array.join().match(/,/g).length + 1)
```

Comment: I was just posting the same `reduce` code ;) Nice solution!

Comment: Upvoted for your kind effort efforts towards helping me.Thanks you so much :)

Comment: your solution in different ways,and the code clearly too,so I'll up it too.